# Small but annoying 'glitches' with drag & drop quiz

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a working drag and drop quiz, put there are some slight design issues I’d like to iron out. I’ve probably been looking at this for a bit too long and could use some fresh eyes. I’ll put the link to the CodePen example and then my notes below.

Example: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/JKaPGN

1. If there’s a really long draggable (yellow) item, the text doesn’t wrap. This is because of `.missing-words__draggable { white-space: nowrap;}`. If you remove the `nowrap` the item will drop onto the next line ...but then when the item is clicked and dragged it ‘jumps’ and text like ‘Co-operatives’ drops onto 2 lines.

**EDIT**

Here's a forked version without `white-space: nowrap` set, you can see when clicking/dragging "private limited company" the text drops onto 2 lines:

http://codepen.io/moy/pen/RRYZVy

**END EDIT**

2. If you drag and answer “Private limited company” (top) and “Franchise (middle), drag move the final answer “Co-operatives” over the other answered boxes, does the item move around unusually like it’s trying to snap to something?
3. On ‘dropping’ a draggable (yellow) item the height of the box changes. I imagine this is due to border. I don’t want to set a fixed height as some of the answers can be quite long so they will need to wrap.

Thanks, hope someone can help!

Comment: for the border problem use outline

Comment: Good shout, never thought of it! I actually adjusted the vertical padding slightly as well which seems to of helps as well. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I think you have "franchise" and "private limited company" reversed as answers.  :)